# SiC inverter design w/ STM32 - high switching frequency

Tags: stm32, power-electronics, inverter

I am designing a SiC inverter using a 72MHz STM32F302CC with the STM32 motor control library. The desired switching frequency is 50-100kHz, depending on the device we select.

Reading the [motor control manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00490980-stm32-motor-control-sdk-stmicroelectronics.pdf), I discovered that "the FOC loop is... executed at the PWM frequency rate (That is: once every PWM Period)." Will I encounter any issues with the complex FOC loop executing so quickly on a 72MHz processor? The only extra processing I plan on doing is some simple state machine logic, receiving torque command CAN messages and sending status CAN messages.

I'm looking into using the STGAP1AS gate driver. Is 100kHz PWM output feasible considering reasonable parasitics? I understand that the typical MCU I/O pin capacitance is 5pF, the gate driver's input should be high impedance (but I can't confirm this in the datasheet), and the MCU and gate driver will reside relatively close on the same PCB.

I am using an STM32F302 because all my other sub-systems use it, but am not opposed to upgrading if necessary to meet the 50-100kHz switching frequency requirement.

Comment: Normally the concern is the gate-driver to the MOSFET, not the MCU to the gate-driver

Comment: The STGAP1AS maximum switching frequency is listed at 150kHz, so I wasn't concerned about that (should I be?). My main concerns were how 100kHz PWM output will look on the board level, and whether a 72MHz processor could run the control algorithm successfully at that speed.

Comment: You should be.  Just because your gate driver can toggle at 150kHz doesn't mean it will actually be able to force the MOSFETs to turn on and off at 150kHz (what if I connect it a MOSFET the size of a house?). Charging and discharging that gate-source capacitance fast enough to turn the MOSFET on and off fast enough is a separate matter from how fast the gate driver theoretically could be under a lower load.

Comment: 72MHz is 720 times faster than 100kHz and the GPIO on the STM32 takes two cycles to toggle, but you won't be using the GPIO. You will be using the PWM module which is even more efficient. It's essentially a non-concern. The input of the gate driver is also tiny compared to the gate of the power MOSFET.

Comment: I feel like this question is really about your specific microcontroller and control theory. I think your gate driving etc. Is not really relevant.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I haven't selected a device yet so I'll have to do some calculations on gate charging and discharging once I do. I won't worry about 100kHz PWM output for now.

About the control algorithm - I have only run simple algorithms at ~10kHz on this 72kHz STM32. Assuming the gate driving is possible at 100kHz, does anybody have experience with running complex algorithms at 100kHz, such as field-oriented control? I'm not sure if I can properly test this without the appropriate hardware.